# Find number of elements across multiple lists and combine; remove if/else complex?

Tags: java, list

I have a list of lists:

```
List<List<String>> someList = new List<List<>>();
```

The maximum size of a list is five strings. It's something like below:

```
someList.get(0).size(); // 4 elements
someList.get(1).size(); // 1 elements
someList.get(2).size(); // 3 elements
someList.get(3).size(); // 1 elements
...
```

I'm trying to devise a method to create a new list of a specific size (1-5 elements) by combining some of the above nested lists. I could do something like the below (in this example, three elements):

```
public List<String> getThree() {
    for (int j = 0; j < someList.size(); j++) {
        //look for nested lists of size 3
        if (someList.get(j).size() == 3) {
            return someList.get(j);
        }
    for (int j = 0; j < someList.size(); j++) {
        //if found nested list of size 2, find one of size 1 to combine
        if (someList.get(j).size() == 2) {
            for (int k = 0; k < someList.size(); k++) {
                if (someList.get(k).size() == 1) {
                    return someList.get(j).add(someList.get(k).get(0));
                }
            }
        }
    for (int j = 0; j < someList.size(); j++) {
        //if found nested list of size 1, find one of size 2 to combine
        if (someList.get(j).size() == 1) {
            for (int l = 0; l < someList.size(); l++) {
                if (someList.get(l).size() == 2) {
                    return someList.get(j).addAll(someList.get(l));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't included the loop for if no sublists are of size 2, to find three of size 1, but you can imagine how long and how ugly it can get. The order is important, thus the for loops incrementing sequentially (ie. I'd rather combine subList 1 + 2 more than 2 + 3, 1 + 3 more than 2 + 3, etc).

I'm hoping to find a way to dynamically implement this. I can only fathom how unreadable and long the `getFive` method will be provided my current methodology. I have multiple methods (getOne through getFive), it doesn't need to be dynamic in this sense, I'd just like to get rid of a lot of the if/else and for loops to reduce complexity and improve readability.

I should mention this is homework related, so I don't quite want a specific answer, but a nudge in the right direction. Something `modulo` perhaps? To do with remainders?

edit; to clarify and give an example:

```
aList = new List<String>;
aList.add("a");
aList.add("b");
someList.add(aList);
bList = new List<String>;
bList.add("c");
someList.add(bList);
newList = someList.getThree();
//newList.size() == 3
//newList contains "a","b","c"
```

The `getThree()` method is creating a new list comprised of elements from the sublists of `someList`. It cannot split a sublist (ie. it can't take 1 element from a sublist of 2 elements), it's combining whole sublists.

Comment: Are you trying to turn the list of lists into a single list?  Am I understanding this right?

Comment: I have to go for about an hour, and if this question is not answered by then I think I have an answer for you.

Comment: Does it matter which lists you combine and what order the items are? Say you have `myList` with sizes `{1, 3, 2, 4, 1}`, and you want a resulting list of `size=5`, are all of the following combinations considered solutions? `{1+3+1}` ,  `{3+2}`,  `{4+either 1}`.

Comment: @Kobit, any amount of lists can be combined, but the leftmost ones take precedence. In your example, it would be `{1+3+1}`. Something like "if it can use sublist 1, use it; if not, if it can use sublist 2, use it; ...".

Comment: Is it you want to keep adding elements from successive lists until you have 5?

Comment: @Robert What about the case for `{1, 3, 2, 4}` and `size=5`? Would the answer be `{1,4}` or would it be `{3,2}`? I'm wondering if the desired solution is always greedy (for example, it tries `{1,3}` and can't fit `4` or `2`, so it tries from `3`.

Comment: @Kobit, it will take the first sublist and attempt to add subsequent lists until it's exhausted or you get to `size=5`, at which point it will try the 2nd with the same process. If it can use the `n`th sublist, it will. It will try its best to use sublist 1, and if not, will then try sublist 2. It will reach `{1,4}` before it reaches `{3,2}`, so `{1,4}` is the combo it will use.

Comment: What is causing your List of Lists to end up in this situation where you're wanting to apply a "fix" after the List of Lists is already made?  Shouldn't you fix the part that is causing this and fix it before it happens instead of after?

Comment: Do you want to use up the lists in the order given, or should the largest one that "fits" always be used first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is to keep collecting from successive lists until you get 5 elements, keep adding then break out when your list is full:

```
public static List<String> fill(List<List<String>> sources, int size) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<String> source : sources) 
        if (source.size() <= size - list.size()) 
            list.addAll(source);
    return list;
}
```

If you want to consume the largest lists first, add this line as the first line of the method:

```
Collections.sort(sources, (a, b) -> b.size() - a.size());
```

---

In java 8, quite succinct:

```
public static List<String> fill(List<List<String>> sources, int size) {
    return sources.stream().reduce(new ArrayList<>(), 
      (a, b) -> {if (b.size() <= a.size() - size) a.addAll(b); return a;});
}
```

and with the largest-first mod:

```
public static List<String> fill(List<List<String>> sources, int size) {
    return sources.stream()
        .sorted((a,b) -> b.size() - a.size())
        .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (a, b) -> 
            {if (b.size() <= a.size() - size) a.addAll(b); return a;});
}
```

Comment: @Shar1er80 I didn't notice that. Actually, allowing for that makes the code a lot simpler. Do you think the edited code does what OP wants now?

Comment: I like your solution better, now that I think I understand better the OP's intentions.  I just don't understand the purpose of returning the same result each time the calls are made.  I think more that the combine would be permanent and not temporary because it seems like you can have conditions where you'll never see a sublist be part of the returned result.

Comment: For example, in the OP's example List of {4, 1, 3, 1} each call to a potential getOne() will always result in the sublist at index 1, and the sublist at index 3 will never be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Since you state that the priority of combining Lists is from left to right.  An O(N^2) loop is sufficient to handle combining sublists to be less than or equal to your desired amount.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<List<String>> someList = new ArrayList() {{
       add(new ArrayList() {{
           add("a1");
           add("a2");
       }});
       add(new ArrayList() {{
           add("b1");
       }});
       add(new ArrayList() {{
           add("c1");
           add("c2");
           add("c3");
       }});
       add(new ArrayList() {{
           add("d1");
       }});
    }};

    combine(someList, 4);

    for(List<String> subList : someList) {
        System.out.println(subList);
    }
}

private static void combine(List<List<String>> someList, int combineAmount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++) {
        // Check if the current list already equals or exceeds the combineAmount
        if (someList.get(i).size() >= combineAmount) {
            continue;
        }

        // Add sublists to the current sublists until the size of the current
        // sublist equals or exceeds the combineAmount
        for (int j = i + 1; j < someList.size(); j++) {
            if (someList.get(i).size() + someList.get(j).size() > combineAmount) {
                continue;
            }
            someList.get(i).addAll(someList.get(j));
            someList.remove(j);
            j--;

            // Don't bother checking other sublists if the newly 
            // combined sublists equals or exceeds the combineAmount
            if (someList.get(i).size() >= combineAmount) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results (combineAmount = 4):

```
[a1, a2, b1, d1]
[c1, c2, c3]
```

Results (combineAmount = 2):

```
[a1, a2]
[b1, d1]
[c1, c2, c3]
```

Results (combineAmount = 6):

```
[a1, a2, b1, c1, c2, c3]
[d1]
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to combine a list of lists into a total of 5 indexes.  When doing this you want it to prioritize the left side first.

Here is a method I have created to do this.  I know you did not want a specific example, but I think an example will help you understand as well as help others who also have this question:

```
private static List<String> getListOf(List<List<String>> someList, int size) {
    List<List<String>> combine = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<List<String>> combinePrev = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int value = 0;
    int indexCloseValue = 0;
    int indexClose;
    for(int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++){//Loops through the lists
        value = someList.get(i).size();
        boolean[] indexAdded = new boolean[someList.size()];//Used to make sure to not add duplicates
        indexAdded[i] = true;
        combine.add(someList.get(i));//add current loop to the combine list.
        do{//A loop to try to add values other than the one of index i to equal size.  This loops multiple times because it may take more than two to equal size.
            indexCloseValue = 0;
            indexClose = -1;
            for(int j = 0; j < someList.size(); j++){
                if(!indexAdded[j]){
                    int listSize = someList.get(j).size();
                    if(value + listSize > indexCloseValue && value + listSize <= size){
                        indexCloseValue = listSize;
                        indexClose = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(indexClose == -1){
                break;
            }else{
                combine.add(someList.get(indexClose));
                value+=indexCloseValue;
                indexAdded[indexClose] = true;
            }
        }while(value + indexCloseValue < size);
        int added = 0;
        for(List<String> str : combine){//Check size of combine list
            added+=str.size();
        }
        int addedPrev = 0;
        for(List<String> str : combinePrev){//Check size of combinePrev list
            addedPrev+=str.size();
        }
        if(added > addedPrev && added <= size){
            combinePrev = new ArrayList<List<String>>(combine);//Set combinePrev to combine if it is larger but less than size
        }
        combine = new ArrayList<List<String>>();//Reset combine
    }

    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(List<String> list : combinePrev){//converts double list to a single list of strings at length "size".
        for(String str : list){
            returnList.add(str);
        }
    }
    return returnList;      
}
```

If there are any problems with this code or you have a question ask me in the comments.